# Group by and order by together in single query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: `topic` and `message`.

Table `topic`:

```
topic_id
// some other not important columns here
```

Table `message`:

```
message_id
topic_id
creation_date
// some other not important columns here
```

As you can see, each topic can have many messages.

What I would like to fetch is: list of all topics (with all topic columns) together with each topic's message count sorted by latest message belonging to topic (topics with most recent messages on top).

This is my try:

```
SELECT topic.*, COUNT(message.message_id)
FROM topic LEFT OUTER JOIN message ON topic.topic_id = message.topic_id
GROUP BY topic.topic_id
ORDER BY message.creation_date DESC
```

This obviously doesn't work. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that your attempt does not work is that there is no `message.creation_date` among the columns produced by the `GROUP BY` query.

You can add it to the output, and use it in a sort, like this:

```
SELECT
    topic.*
,   COUNT(message.message_id) cnt
,   MAX(message.creation_date) last_msg
FROM topic LEFT OUTER JOIN message ON topic.topic_id = message.topic_id
GROUP BY topic.topic_id
ORDER BY last_msg DESC
```

You should be able to do ordering without defining a column for it, like this:

```
SELECT topic.*, COUNT(message.message_id)
FROM topic LEFT OUTER JOIN message ON topic.topic_id = message.topic_id
GROUP BY topic.topic_id
ORDER BY MAX(message.creation_date) DESC
```